# FuelUX Wizard component - how to manually select active step?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wizard, fuelux

I'm not seeing any documentation for this.

How do you manually select which panel is active in the wizard component?

I know it's in there somewhere because you can click on one of the tabs once it's been passed, and navigate back to a previous tab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can change [wizard step](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/pull/210):

```
$('#MyWizard').wizard('selectItem', { step: step });
```

UPDATE:

After the last updates now it works with selectedItem

```
$('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem', { step: step });
```

Note the change from select to selected*.

Comment: This was added in after my original inquiry. It's now the standard method of accessing the step tabs.

Comment: I understand. This answer is not for you, but for those who will seek a solution in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to directly set the active panel since the upcoming steps are disabled until activated using prev/next.

Once a step has been "activated" you could use jquery to trigger a tab click..

```
$('[data-target=#step2]').trigger("click");
```

Here is a working example: **http://www.bootply.com/60319** -- If you navigate to the last step (5), there is a link that returns to step 2.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!  I added a GitHub issue to enable this through a more accessible method: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/194

Answer (score 2):

$('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem', { step: currentStep });

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I wanted to share what worked for me in Fuel FX 2.x:

```
$('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem', { step: YourStepNumber });
```

E.g.:

```
$('#wizard1').wizard('selectedItem', { step: 7 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wizard').wizard();
    $('#wizard').find('ul.steps li').toggleClass('complete', true);

    $('#wizard').on('changed.fu.wizard', function (evt, data) {
        $('#wizard').find('ul.steps li').toggleClass('complete', true);
    });
});
```

This makes all steps clickable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', function()
{
$('#orderWizard').wizard('next');
}
```

Above Code is for Manually Get the Next Pane
for Previous One you can try Belowed One

```
$('#btnPrev').on('click', function()
{
$('#orderWizard').wizard('previous');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "active" class on the **li** tag and when renders the wizard, the acvite **li** is marked.

This is a example in symfony:

```
<li data-target="#step1" class="complete">
  <span class="step">1</span>
</li>
<li data-target="#step2" class="active">
  <span class="step">2</span>
</li>
```